# Getting fields_for and accepts_nested_attributes_for to work with a belongs_to relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, nested-attributes

I cannot seem to get a nested form to generate in a rails view for a `belongs_to` relationship using the new `accepts_nested_attributes_for` facility of Rails 2.3. I did check out many of the resources available and it looks like my code *should* be working, but `fields_for` explodes on me, and I suspect that it has something to do with how I have the nested models configured.

The error I hit is a common one that can have many causes:

```
'@account[owner]' is not allowed as an instance variable name
```

Here are the two models involved:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Relationships
  belongs_to :owner, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'owner_id'
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :owner
  has_many :users
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account
end
```

Perhaps this is where I am doing it 'rong', as an Account can have an 'owner', and may 'users', but a user only has one 'account', based on the user model account_id key.

This is the view code in new.html.haml that blows up on me:

```
- form_for :account, :url => account_path do |account|
  = account.text_field :name
  - account.fields_for :owner do |owner|
    = owner.text_field :name
```

And this is the controller code for the new action:

```
class AccountsController < ApplicationController
  # GET /account/new
  def new
    @account  = Account.new
  end
end
```

When I try to load /account/new I get the following exception:

```
NameError in Accounts#new
Showing app/views/accounts/new.html.haml where line #63 raised:
@account[owner] is not allowed as an instance variable name
```

If I try to use the mysterious 'build' method, it just bombs out in the controller, perhaps because build is just for multi-record relationships:

```
class AccountsController < ApplicationController
  # GET /account/new
  def new
    @account  = Account.new
    @account.owner.build
  end
end

You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
The error occurred while evaluating nil.build
```

If I try to set this up using @account.owner_attributes = {} in the controller, or @account.owner = User.new, I'm back to the original error, "@account[owner] is not allowed as an instance variable name".

Does anybody else have the new accepts_nested_attributes_for method working with a belongs_to relationship? Is there something special or different you have to do? All the official examples and sample code (like the [great stuff over at Ryans Scraps](http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2009/2/1/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-nested-attributes)) is concerned with multi-record associations.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think your `accepts_nested_attributes` is on the wrong side of the relationship. Maybe something like this would work?

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'owner_id'
  has_many :users
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account
  has_one :account, :foreign_key => :owner_id
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :account
end
```

For building the account you want to use build_account.

You can see more examples in [the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html).

Comment: D'oh! That would do it. I may actually change this so that Account has_one :owner, and User belong_to :owned_account or :team or something, and set the foreign  key.

Comment: accepts_nested_attributes_for can be on either side of the relationship (at least I've confirmed for has_one, belongs_to). I assume a has_many functions the same.

Answer (score 46):

I'm a few months too late, but I was looking to solve this error and my situation was that I could not change the relationship to 'face the other way'.

The answer really is quite simple, you have to do this in your new action:

```
@account.build_owner
```

The reason why the form did not display using fields_for was because it did not have a valid object. You had the right idea up there with:

```
@account.owner.build
```

However, this is not the way `belongs_to` work. This method is only generated with `has_many` and `has_and_belongs_to_many`.

Reference:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#belongs-to-association-reference

Comment: But the build_ method doesn't exist in polymorphic relation.

Comment: @Jaryl, Works like a charm... :) Please comment on "what should be done when same form is rendered while editing, and has nested attributes for belongs_to association.".

Comment: @zeal a month late again, but ideally nothing further needs to be done to handle both creating and editing. Both form_for and accepts_nested_attributes_for work hand in hand to generate form elements such that the id is present for existing records, and if it is not, it will just generate []. It event works for has_many associations in the same way, but with an additional [] to maintain some indexing.

Some caveats to take note of is that with strong params, you will need to permit owner_attributes: [:account_id, :your_data], where the foreign key allows the association to be maintained.

Comment: Apparently this **extremely unintuitive** behaviour is intended this way https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/2709#issuecomment-4859798

Answer (score 8):

I'm using Rails 2.3.5 and I noticed the same thing.  Checking out the source for active_record's nested_attributes.rb, it looks like belongs_to should work fine.  So it appears it might be a "nested forms" bug.

I have a nested form exactly like yours, with `User belongs_to :address`, and `Address` is independent of the user.

Then in the form, I just do `<% f.fields_for :address_attributes do |address_form| %>` instead of `<% f.fields_for :address do |address_form| %>`.  Temporary hack until there's a better way, but this works.  The method `accepts_nested_attributes_for` is expecting the params to include something like:

`{user=>{address_attributes=>{attr1=>'one',attr2=>'two'}, name=>'myname'}`

...but `fields_for` is producing:

`{user=>{address=>{attr1=>'one',attr2=>'two'}, name=>'myname'}`

This way you don't have to add that `has_one :account` to your code, which doesn't work in my case.

Update: Found a better answer:

Here is the gist of the code I'm using to make this work right:

[Rails Nested Forms with belongs_to Gist](http://gist.github.com/276659)

Hope that helps.

Answer (score -3):

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :owner  :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'owner_id'
end
```

It works for me. :foreign_key => 'owner_id' was the key problem in my case.