# Rails 4, validating nested models

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have 2 models:

```
class Person
  has_one :user
  validates :document, uniqueness: true, on: :create

class User
  belongs_to :person
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :person
```

Then i have a form for `users` that information about the `person`:

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :person do |person_fields| %>
    <%= person_fields.label "Document" %>
    <%= person_fields.text_field :document %>
  <% end %>  
  <%= f.label "Username" %>
  <%= f.text_field :username %>
<% end %>
```

When i go for `/users/edit/1` for example, it loads the user its person attributes. If i change the `username` and save, it says that `the document number is already at use`, bypassing the `person` validation of `uniqueness` only on `create`.

Am i missing something here? Are validations like this not supposed to work on nested forms?

Comment: I guess you have to use `reject_if:` option

Comment: Why validate uniqueness only on create ?

Comment: Can you also show your `user_controller`, especially the `user_params` strong parameters method ?

Answer (score 0):

### Nested attributes allow you to save attributes on associated records through the parent (has_one, has_many), not on the parent through the child (belongs_to).

Your model relationship is not correct; According to Rails [api](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) nested attributes are valid for the child through the parent, not the parent through the child as you have specified in your models below.

**Your models**

```
class Person
  has_one :user
  validates :document, uniqueness: true, on: :create

class User
  belongs_to :person
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :person (sets up nested attributes for parent)
```

You could set up nested attributes for the child via the parent, as such

**Suggested change**

```
class Person
  has_one :user
  validates :document, uniqueness: true, on: :create
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user

class User
  belongs_to :person
```

---

Nesting on your form will work only if the nesting associations in the model are set up properly.

### Sidebar: The beauty of :Inverse_of

This is a sidebar, but relevant in this context. Inverse_of gives you a reverse reference from the child to the parent. [Rails spec for :inverse_of](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html). You should try this out and see how it works for your app. It's a very good thing.

```
    class Person
      has_one :user, inverse_of: person
      validates :document, uniqueness: true, on: :create
      accepts_nested_attributes_for :user

   class User
     belongs_to :person, inverse_of: user
```

### Debugging questions (added)

I added the on: :create validation to one of my models as a test. I would ask you do a similar test without the model nesting; I think it's informative to test the logic in the model for the on: create, which will validate the controller actions. And only then layer on the nesting attributes. What do you think?

Duplicate field on create => ROLLBACK

```
Started POST "/locations" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-07-20 08:03:36 -0500
Processing by LocationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Fxxx", "location"=>{"name"=>"Foo", "food_trailer"=>"true", "street"=>"100 Main", "city"=>"Fredericksburg", "state"=>"Texas", "country"=>"US", "phone"=>"", "website"=>"", "short_desc"=>"A Texan, Ms. Diana has been cookin' up barbecue for 50 years and, spreadin' the “barbecue love” in Paris (France!) since 2010.", "known_for"=>"Tings", "meats_beef"=>"0", "meats_beef_ribs"=>"0", "meats_pork"=>"1", "meats_pork_ribs"=>"0", "meats_chicken"=>"0", "meats_turkey"=>"0", "meats_sausage"=>"0", "meats_venison"=>"0", "sauce"=>"0", "sides"=>"None"}, "commit"=>"Add Restaurant"}
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", 8]]
  [1m[35m (0.0ms)[0m  BEGIN
  [1m[36mLocation Exists (46.9ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  1 AS one FROM "locations" WHERE "locations"."short_desc" = 'A Texan, Ms. Diana has been cookin'' up barbecue for 50 years and, spreadin'' the “barbecue love” in Paris (France!) since 2010.' LIMIT 1[0m
  [1m[35mLocation Exists (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "locations" WHERE ("locations"."latitude" IS NULL AND "locations"."longitude" IS NULL) LIMIT 1
  [1m[36m (46.9ms)[0m  [1mROLLBACK[0m
```

Duplicate field on edit => COMMIT

```
Started PATCH "/locations/46" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-07-20 08:04:30 -0500
Processing by LocationsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"xxx", "location"=>{"name"=>"Grillrestaurant Rusticana", "street"=>"Grillparzerstraße 5, 81675", "city"=>"München", "state"=>"Alabama", "country"=>"US", "phone"=>"", "website"=>"", "short_desc"=>"A Texan, Ms. Diana has been cookin' up barbecue for 50 years and, spreadin' the “barbecue love” in Paris (France!) since 2010.", "known_for"=>"", "meats_beef"=>"0", "meats_beef_ribs"=>"0", "meats_pork"=>"0", "meats_pork_ribs"=>"0", "meats_chicken"=>"0", "meats_turkey"=>"0", "meats_sausage"=>"0", "meats_venison"=>"0", "sauce"=>"0", "sides"=>""}, "commit"=>"Save changes to Restaurant", "id"=>"46"}
  [1m[36mLocation Load (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  "locations".* FROM "locations" WHERE "locations"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", 46]]
  [1m[35m (0.0ms)[0m  BEGIN
  [1m[36mLocation Exists (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  1 AS one FROM "locations" WHERE ("locations"."latitude" = 48.1334073 AND "locations"."id" != 46 AND "locations"."longitude" = 11.6100255) LIMIT 1[0m
  [1m[35mSQL (15.6ms)[0m  UPDATE "locations" SET "short_desc" = $1, "meats_beef" = $2, "meats_pork" = $3, "meats_beef_ribs" = $4, "meats_pork_ribs" = $5, "meats_chicken" = $6, "meats_turkey" = $7, "meats_sausage" = $8, "meats_venison" = $9, "sauce" = $10, "latitude" = $11, "updated_at" = $12 WHERE "locations"."id" = $13  [["short_desc", "A Texan, Ms. Diana has been cookin' up barbecue for 50 years and, spreadin' the “barbecue love” in Paris (France!) since 2010."], ["meats_beef", "f"], ["meats_pork", "f"], ["meats_beef_ribs", "f"], ["meats_pork_ribs", "f"], ["meats_chicken", "f"], ["meats_turkey", "f"], ["meats_sausage", "f"], ["meats_venison", "f"], ["sauce", "f"], ["latitude", 48.13340729999999], ["updated_at", "2015-07-20 13:04:30.437500"], ["id", 46]]
  [1m[36m (46.9ms)[0m  [1mCOMMIT[0m
```

Comment: Let me try your suggestion. One question, do i have to change the form too? I am using a `user` form. Do i have to build a `person` one?

Comment: Yes. Flip the logic in your form to person/user instead of user/person.

Comment: One thing, the form example you posted doesn't have a submit/button, so I assume you left this out on purpose for the example. Or, are you using the form for display only?

Comment: Hmmm it works for me with nested attributes on `belongs_to` ! I'm using Mongoid and not ActiveRecord though, but I don't see why that would be a problem ?

Comment: @CyrilDD I don't know Mongoid. Might be different, since it's not using Active Record. According to the Rails spec w/ Act. Rec. the nested attr. relationship works solely through the parent to the child. If you have seen the opposite successfully done, I would certainly be willing to change my position.

Comment: Hmm now that you mention it, I am using the `nested_form` gem, so maybe this gem makes it work for `belong_to`. But anyway, I don't understand why it would not work for `belongs_to`. The only difference between `has_one` and `belongs_to` is the location of the foreign key ?

Comment: Some answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7365895/does-accepts-nested-attributes-for-work-with-belongs-to) seem to confirm `accepts_nested_attributes` works with `belongs_to` with Rails 4.

Comment: I don't see an answer that confirms that.

Comment: I think we should see what @MurifoX comes back with. SO is complaining that we're having too much discussion in the comments.

Comment: I have inverted the logic, created a form based on `@person` and the `nested` part is now for the user. Put a `validates :username, uniqueness: true, on: :create` on my `User` model and tried to update an existing record. Rails fails to validate it saying that the `username` is already on the database, ignoring the `on: :create` part, just like the other way around. I still don't get it.

Comment: Would you please post your updated models? This is a very interesting problem.

Comment: Also, would you post the logs showing the database access.  I think it must be executing a POST and not a PATCH. Possible?