# assign child to one of parents in rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have problem how to create form for assigning child to one of parents. My child-nodes are defined in system, i go to child (alias) and want to assign it to one of parents contacts) (or create new). How do I create such form?

```
class Alias < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :contact    
end


class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :aliases
  belongs_to :user
end
```

So i have couple objects of Alias and couple of Contact, but I don't want to go to Contact and there assign Alias, but go to Alias, and pickup one of Contacts from (example) select box.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to select the association id. A select box is probably the most space efficient on a page, but sometimes radio buttons work nice if there are few possible associations.

I think something like this might suit you. This assumes you assign `@contacts` to something like `Contact.all` inside your controller.

```
= form_for @alias do |f|
  = f.label :contact_id, "Contact"
  = f.collection_select :contact_id, @contacts, :id, :full_names
```

This assumes you have a field called "full_names" in your contact. Put whatever field you want to show in the select box.

Creating the `Contact` from the `Alias` is more tricky, and personally I wouldn't recommend it. Here are a couple questions which explain how to do it though:

[Does accepts_nested_attributes_for work with belongs_to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7365895/does-accepts-nested-attributes-for-work-with-belongs-to)

[Getting fields_for and accepts_nested_attributes_for to work with a belongs_to relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313149/getting-fields-for-and-accepts-nested-attributes-for-to-work-with-a-belongs-to-r/2441463#2441463)

I hope that helps.