# Rails associated model callbacks not fired

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, callback, nested

I use `accepts_nested_attributes` in my model parent and the parent model has belongs_to association with children model. I am trying to use callbacks in my children model (`after_update`, `after_create`).When update_attributes used in parents_controller to update the parent record.The callbacks `after_create` is working fine but `after_update` is not triggering.

```
class Parent
  accepts_nested_attributes :children
  belongs_to :children
end
class Children
  before_save :saving
  after_update :test
  has_many :parents
end
```

Help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you include the line, which makes the update?

Comment: @santhosh @parent.update_attributes!(params[:parent])

Comment: Does params[:parent] contain children attributes ?

Comment: @santhosh yes,It contains children attributes.

Comment: `class Children; accepts_nested_attributes :parent; end` and remove `accepts_nested_attributes :children`

Comment: The `accepts_nested_attributes` method is meant to work for the class with the has_many/has_one relationship. It won't work on your Parent class which maintains the `belongs_to` association. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313149/getting-fields-for-and-accepts-nested-attributes-for-to-work-with-a-belongs-to-r