# Nested forms in ruby on rails using has_many through and belongs to associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, activerecord, nested-forms

Lets say I have three objects/models; years, cars, and parts. Now, I have cars belong_to parts. The thought on this was that a part may be part of many cars but a car has only one of that part at a given time. and years has_many cars through car_years. I have successfully nested the cars form in the years form. However, when I try to nest the parts form in the cars form and create a new year I get cannot mass assign protected: parts. But, I can create a new car and it will successfully create the new part. I would like to know if I am on the right track or should I be looking elsewhere to solve this. I got the idea from rails cast #196.

**Year model**

```
class Year < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :year, :cars_attributes

  has_many :car_years  
  has_many :cars, :through => :machine_years

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :car_years,
    :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:num_cars].blank? }, 
    :allow_destroy => true 

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :cars,
    :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:doors].blank? }, 
    :allow_destroy => true 

end
```

**Car model**

```
class Machine < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible ..., :part_id, :part_attributes

  has_many :car_years
  has_many :years, :through => :car_years
  belongs_to :part

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :car_years
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :years

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :part,
    :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:name].blank? }

end
```

**Parts Model**

```
class Part < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :desc, :name

  has_many :machines
end
```

**Year_form View**

```
<%= form_for(@year) do |f| %>
  <% if @year.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">    
      <h2><%= pluralize(@year.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this year from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>                 
      <% @year.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">      
    <%= f.label :year %><br />
    <%= f.date_select :year, :start_year => 1940, :end_year => Time.now.year, :discard_day => true, :discard_mon    th => true %>
  </div>

    <h3>Cars</h3>      
    <div>
      <%= f.fields_for :cars do |builder| %>
        <%= render 'car_fields', :f => builder %>
      <% end %>            
      <p><%= link_to_add_fields "Add Car", f, :cars %></p>
    </div>                 

  </div>

  <div class="actions">    
    <%= f.submit %>        
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**Car_fields.html.erb**

```
<div class="field">
  <h3>New Car</h3>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th><%= f.label :name %></th>
        <th><%= f.label :model %></th>
        <th><%= f.label :part_id %></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><%= f.text_field :name %></td>
        <td><%= f.text_field :model %></td>
        <td>
          <%= f.fields_for :part do |builder| %>
            <%= render "cars/parts_fields", :f => builder %>
          <% end %>
        </td>
        <td><%= f.number_field :memory_id %></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th><%= f.label :install_dt, "Install Date" %></th>
        <th></th>
        <th><%= f.label :production_dt, "Production Date" %></th>
        <th></th>
        <th><%= f.label :remove_dt, "Remove Date" %></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><%= f.date_select :install_dt, :start_year => 1940, :end_year => Time.now.year %></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><%= f.date_select :production_dt, :start_year => 1940, :end_year => Time.now.year %></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><%= f.date_select :remove_dt, :start_year => 1940, :end_year => Time.now.year %></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th><%= f.label :history %></th>
        <th></th>
        <th><%= f.label :design %></th>
        <th></th>
        <th><%= f.label :notes %></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><%= f.text_area :history, :rows => 4 %></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><%= f.text_area :design, :rows => 4 %></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><%= f.text_area :notes, :rows => 4 %></td>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
   </table>
  <div style="padding: 2px;">
    <%= f.label :image %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :image %>
  </div>
  <%= link_to_function "remove", "remove_fields(this)" %>
</div>
```

**cars/part_fields.html.erb**

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :name %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :name %><br /> 
  <%= f.label :desc %><br />
  <%= f.text_area :desc, :rows => 3 %>
</div>
```

Comment: Does a car really belong to a _single_ part?

Comment: can you post some of your code?

Comment: Please add your models, the form and the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell without seeing any of you code. However the following error `cannot mass assign protected: parts` means that you should add `attr_accessible :parts` to your model in order to be able to do something like this:

```
a_part = Part.new
another_part = Part.new
Car.new(parts: [a_part, another_part])
```

Otherwise, without it, you would have to do:

```
c = Car.new
c.parts << a_part
c.parts << another_part
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, so the solution was in another post:
[Getting fields_for and accepts_nested_attributes_for to work with a belongs_to relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313149/getting-fields-for-and-accepts-nested-attributes-for-to-work-with-a-belongs-to-r)

In the car_fields form I needed to call

```
<%= f.fields_for :part_attributes do |builder| %>
```

not

```
<% =f.fields_for :parts do |builder| %>
```

However, now when I look at the year edit screen the part fields are empty, but the part_type does exist