# fields_for a nested resource not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following associations:

```
class Campaign < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :campaign
  belongs_to :venue
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :venue
end

class Venue < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events
end
```

And I have the following form:

```
<%= form_for([@campaign, @event]) do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :venue do |v| %>
    <%= v.text_field :search %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Anything in the `fields_for` block is not showing up.  But the funny thing is if i change `f.fields_for :venue` to `f.fields_for :venues`, the `:search` field shows up.

But :venues shouldn't be plural on :events.  Even in rails console Event.venues does not work

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `venues'
```

It also generates the wrong field names

This makes me think I have my model associations jacked up, but after reviewing the docs. it does not seem so.  Here is my schema for reference:

```
  create_table "campaigns", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "description"
    t.integer  "image_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "events", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "campaign_id"
    t.datetime "start_date"
    t.datetime "end_date"
    t.integer  "venue_id"
    t.integer  "image_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "description"
  end

  create_table "venues", force: true do |t|
    t.float    "latitude"
    t.float    "longitude"
    t.string   "address1"
    t.string   "address2"
    t.string   "city"
    t.string   "zip"
    t.string   "state"
    t.string   "country"
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "gid"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the similar SO Posts

1.**[Does accepts_nested_attributes_for work with belongs_to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7365895/does-accepts-nested-attributes-for-work-with-belongs-to)**

2.**[Getting fields_for and accepts_nested_attributes_for to work with a belongs_to relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313149/getting-fields-for-and-accepts-nested-attributes-for-to-work-with-a-belongs-to-r)**

As mentioned in one of those posts,one way of achieving it is changing the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` to the `has_many` side

```
class Campaign < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :events
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :campaign
  belongs_to :venue

end

class Venue < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :events
end
```

If it is not,you might want to build a `venue` for `events` with `@event.build_venue` in the controller before calling `fields_for`.

Hope it helps!

Comment: It does work for belongs_to, at least in rails4.  But the 2nd answer of your 2nd link is the correct answer.  I needed to call @event.build_venue before fields_for knew how to pick it up.  My associations were correctly set up after all.  If you want to rearrange your answer I'll mark it as the correct one.

Comment: @Vigrond I think now it looks ok.Anyways glad you figured it out.